# Calculate an incremental mean using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to generate a series that's the incremental mean of a timeseries.  Meaning that, starting from the first date (index 0), the mean stored in row x is the average of values [0:x]

```
data
index   value   mean          formula
0       4
1       5
2       6
3       7       5.5           average(0-3)
4       4       5.2           average(0-4)
5       5       5.166666667   average(0-5)
6       6       5.285714286   average(0-6)
7       7       5.5           average(0-7)
```

I'm hoping there's a way to do this without looping to take advantage of pandas.

Comment: You're looking for an [`expanding_mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.stats.moments.expanding_mean.html)

Like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092629/applying-cumulative-mean-function-to-a-grouped-object/21093297#21093297) but without the groupby.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here's an update for newer versions of Pandas (starting with 0.18.0)

```
df['value'].expanding().mean()
```

or

```
s.expanding().mean()
```

Answer (score 16):

As @TomAugspurger points out, you can use [`expanding_mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#expanding-window-moment-functions):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [12]: pd.expanding_mean(s, 4)
Out[12]: 
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3    5.500000
4    5.200000
5    5.166667
6    5.285714
7    5.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please also check out the answer by jpobst for Pandas later than 0.18.0

Comment: Link is dead....

Answer (score 11):

Another approach is to use cumsum(), and divide by the cumulative number of items, for example:

```
In [1]:
    s = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    s.cumsum() / pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(s)+1), s.index)

Out[1]:
0    4.000000
1    4.500000
2    5.000000
3    5.500000
4    5.200000
5    5.166667
6    5.285714
7    5.500000
dtype: float64
```