# Dataframe : How do I perform the below calculation in one of my columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

HI I want to add another column to the below dataframe which gives me the rolling mean of the numbers in column 'value'

so the first number will be 75 itself, 2nd will be 42.5((75+10)/2), 3rd will be 59.67((75+10+94)/3) and so on...

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142149/calculate-an-incremental-mean-using-python-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437657/rolling-mean-on-pandas-on-a-specific-column

Comment: thanks @Zeeshan that was useful as well !

Answer (score 0):

you can this code:

```
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['0', 75], ['1', 10], ['2', 94], ['3', 96]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['index', 'value']) 
df["avrage"]=df['value'].expanding().mean()

# print dataframe. 
df 


index   value   avrage
0   0   75  75.000000
1   1   10  42.500000
2   2   94  59.666667
3   3   96  68.750000
```