# How to fill the null values with the average of all the preceeding values before null and first succeeding value after null in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, python-requests

[image]I have a dataframe with 5000 records. I want the null values to be filled with:

Average(All the Preceding values before null, First succeeding value after null)

```
data:

Date          gcs     Comp     Clay       WTS
2020-01-01    1550     41      9.41      22.6
2020-01-02    1540     48      9.50      25.8
2020-01-03    NAN      NAN     NAN        NAN
2020-01-04    1542     42      9.30      23.7
2020-01-05    1580     48      9.10      21.2
2020-01-06    NAN     NAN      NAN       NAN
2020-01-07    1520     40      10        20.2
2020-01-08    1523     30      25         19
```

Example:
For the date 2020-01-03, i want the null value in the gcs column to be filled with the Average(1550,1540,1542) which gives 1544.

1550 and 1540 are the preceding values before null and 1542 is my first succeeding value after null.

Similarly,

For the date 2020-01-06 i want the null values for gcs column to be filled with
Average(1550,1540,1544,1542,1580,1520) which gives 1546.

1550 till 1580 are the preceding values before null and 1520 is the first succeeding value after null.

```
Desired Output:

Date          gcs     Comp     Clay       WTS
2020-01-01    1550     41      9.41      22.6
2020-01-02    1540     48      9.50      25.8
2020-01-03    1544     43.66   9.403     24.03
2020-01-04    1542     42      9.30      23.7
2020-01-05    1580     48      9.10      21.2
2020-01-06    1546     43.77   9.45      22.92
2020-01-07    1520     40      10        20.2
2020-01-08    1523     30      25         19
```

**Edit:

Thanks for the response Tom.
i kept my date column as index and tried the below code:

```
def foo(row):
    if any(row.isna()):
        df.loc[row.name,row.isna()] = df.expanding().mean().shift(-1).loc[row.name,:]
df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

The output that i got is :

```
Date
2020-01-01    None
2020-01-02    None
2020-01-03    None
2020-01-04    None
2020-01-05    None
2020-01-06    None
2020-01-07    None
2020-01-08    None
dtype: object
```

Can you please help me figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tom. I am getting all null values as output can you please help me figure out what is wrong, since i am new to python i might make mistakes even in some basics

Comment: Any help from anybody on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: You should post comments/questions about an answer under that answer, jsyk!  Are you doing `df  = df.apply(foo, axis=1)` or `df.apply(foo, axis=1)`.  This operation is a little strange for `apply` b/c it is modified `df` but *returns nothing* (see that there is no `return` in `foo`).  So if you reassign `df` with "=" you get an empty DataFrame.  I'm just taking a stab at what might be wrong, might be something else

Comment: But the answer works for me; though I did set "Date" as the index, and I made sure the numbers are `float` (not `str` or `object` or something); you could verify that your "NAN" are really null values (and get picked up by `row.isna`).  If you need more explanation on the answer, I am happy to post more

Comment: Do i need to define or mention what is "row" before the function? Because i do not have anything as row before the function . Image of my code is attached. @Tom

Comment: row.isna returns all the values as False. If i do df.isna then the output is boolean with True in the place of null values and False in the place of non null values.

Comment: i tried to assign row = df[['gcs','Comp','Clay',WTS']] and then i ran the function but still the output is None for all the values.

Comment: Ah you need to inspect `df` now!  Either run `df` in a new cell, or after the `apply` line add `df`.  With `apply(func, axis=1)`, an object (Series or DataFrame) will be returned with the result of `func` for each row.  But if `func` returns nothing, you get `NaN` for each row - as you see.  *However* if `func` is modifying something else (like `df`), those changes still take place.  So your object `df` has been updated!  A simpler example of this is a method like `append` for lists; if you run `ls.append(x)` in a console, you get no return (and in fact `ls.append(x) == None` is `True`)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work.  You define an `apply` function for the rows which modifies the `df` in place.  Each time a row (with null values) is reached you can take an `expanding` mean of `df`([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43414120/13386979)), using a `shift` to include the following row.  You then use `loc` to overwrite `df` with the new values:

```
def foo(row):
    if any(row.isna()):
        df.loc[row.name,row.isna()] = df.expanding().mean().shift(-1).loc[row.name,:]
```

Applying:

```
>>>df.apply(foo, axis=1)

               gcs       Comp       Clay        WTS
Date                                               
2020-01-01  1550.0  41.000000   9.410000  22.600000
2020-01-02  1540.0  48.000000   9.500000  25.800000
2020-01-03  1544.0  43.666667   9.403333  24.033333
2020-01-04  1542.0  42.000000   9.300000  23.700000
2020-01-05  1580.0  48.000000   9.100000  21.200000
2020-01-06  1546.0  43.777778   9.452222  22.922222
2020-01-07  1520.0  40.000000  10.000000  20.200000
2020-01-08  1523.0  30.000000  25.000000  19.000000
```

Note that I moved your `Date` column to be an index.  I think the above should work wherever the missing values are, ensuring that the values are filled in from top to bottom.

I'm not sure how it will handle scaling up to 5000 rows, but it seems like you have to use `apply` or some loop b/c you want to include imputed values in the calculation of future imputed values*.  I added the `if` statement b/c it seemed to speed up the calculation considerably:

```
%%timeit
df.apply(foo, axis=1)
#1.17 ms ± 25.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.apply(foo_without_if, axis=1)
#16.2 ms ± 201 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*if you don't want to do this (i.e. you can just take the rolling mean but ignore NAs from earlier rows), you can do:

```
mask = df.isna()
df[mask] = df.expanding().mean()[mask.shift(1)].shift(-1)
```