# How can i fill the null values in a datafame with a specific condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(1,16), columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])

a = [1550, 41, 9.41, 22.6, 4.74, 3.2, 11.64, 2.23]
b = [1540, 43, 9.41, 22.3, 4.84, 3.12, 11.64, 2.23]
c = [1590, 39, 9.41, 23.7, 4.74, 3.0, 11.64, 2.23]
d = [1540, 41, 9.41, 22.5, 4.74, 3.2, 11.64, 2.23]

df.loc[[1,8,13,15],:] = [a,b,c,d]
```

Looking like this:

```
         A     B     C     D     E     F      G     H
1   1550.0  41.0  9.41  22.6  4.74  3.20  11.64  2.23
2      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
3      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
4      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
5      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
6      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
7      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
8   1540.0  43.0  9.41  22.3  4.84  3.12  11.64  2.23
9      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
10     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
11     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
12     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
13  1590.0  39.0  9.41  23.7  4.74  3.00  11.64  2.23
14     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
15  1540.0  41.0  9.41  22.5  4.74  3.20  11.64  2.23
```

I want the null values to be filled with:
"Average(All the preceding values before null, first non-null succeeding value after null)"
Note:If the first succeeding value after null is also Null, then the code should look for the first succeeding value which is not null .

Example:
Row 2 of column A should be filled with Average(1550,1540) = 1545

Here "All Preceding value before null" = 1550, "First non null succeeding value after null" = 1540

Similarly,
row 3 of column A should be filled with Average(1550,1545,1540) = 1545

Here all the preceding value before the null are 1550 and 1545(1545 is what we found in the above step)

First non null succeeding value after null is again 1540 .

It goes on like that and row 9 of column A should be filled with

Average(All the values before the null, 1590) 1590 is now the first non null succeeding value after null.

So at the end my desired output in Column A looks like this:

```
Desired Output Example for A column: 

Row   A
1   1550
2   1545
3   1545
4   1545
5   1545
6   1545
7   1545
8   1540
9   1550
10  1550
11  1550
12  1550
13  1590
14  1549.285
15  1540
```

Similarly i wanted my null values to be filled for all the other columns as well.
Since i am new to python I dont know how to write a code for this.

Any help on the code is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your code in which you declare your dataframe?

Comment: @Anton the code is shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very similar post to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924126/how-to-fill-the-null-values-with-the-average-of-all-the-preceeding-values-before/62925092#62925092), but I suppose this is different enough (and the operation convoluted enough) to warrant a different answer.

You can define an `apply` function to use for every row:

```
def foo(row):
    if any(row.isna()):
        next_non_null = df.loc[df.index>row.name, row.isna()].dropna(how='all').index[0]
        df.loc[row.name, row.isna()] = df.expanding().mean().loc[next_non_null, :]
```

The basic logic is this:

- loop over `df` and look at every row.  for every row:
- check if there are any missing values in the row (this can save time, see the post linked above)
- if there are, find the index of the next non-null entry for those missing values: take `df` with the empty values dropped, and find the rows in that which are greater than the current row, and take the first index
- rewrite the current rows empty values with those from the `expanding` mean of the `df` at the first non-null value

Applying this function is then simply:

```
df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

Converting `df` into:

```
             A          B     C          D         E         F      G     H
1   1550.000000  41.000000  9.41  22.600000  4.740000  3.200000  11.64  2.23
2   1545.000000  42.000000  9.41  22.450000  4.790000  3.160000  11.64  2.23
3   1545.000000  42.000000  9.41  22.450000  4.790000  3.160000  11.64  2.23
4   1545.000000  42.000000  9.41  22.450000  4.790000  3.160000  11.64  2.23
5   1545.000000  42.000000  9.41  22.450000  4.790000  3.160000  11.64  2.23
6   1545.000000  42.000000  9.41  22.450000  4.790000  3.160000  11.64  2.23
7   1545.000000  42.000000  9.41  22.450000  4.790000  3.160000  11.64  2.23
8   1540.000000  43.000000  9.41  22.300000  4.840000  3.120000  11.64  2.23
9   1550.000000  41.666667  9.41  22.588889  4.784444  3.142222  11.64  2.23
10  1550.000000  41.666667  9.41  22.588889  4.784444  3.142222  11.64  2.23
11  1550.000000  41.666667  9.41  22.588889  4.784444  3.142222  11.64  2.23
12  1550.000000  41.666667  9.41  22.588889  4.784444  3.142222  11.64  2.23
13  1590.000000  39.000000  9.41  23.700000  4.740000  3.000000  11.64  2.23
14  1549.285714  41.619048  9.41  22.582540  4.781270  3.146349  11.64  2.23
15  1540.000000  41.000000  9.41  22.500000  4.740000  3.200000  11.64  2.23
```

I'm not going to check if the other columns are right

**But note, this `apply` is modifying `df` in place, but returning an empty DataFrame.**  So if you are working in a console and run the `apply` line, you will see a DataFrame of `None` returned.  But if you check `df` again after, you should see that it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fill_nulls(ls):
    non_null_index = [i for i in range(len(ls)) if not np.isnan(ls[i])]
    non_null_values = [i for i in ls if not np.isnan(i)]
    if 0 not in non_null_index:
        ls[0] = non_null_values[0]
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        if i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            if np.isnan(ls[i]):
                left_non_null = [j for j in ls[:i] if not np.isnan(j)]
                right_non_null = [[j for j in ls[i:] if not np.isnan(j)][0]]
                fill_value = np.mean(left_non_null + right_non_null)
                ls[i] = fill_value
            else:
                pass
            
    return ls

df['A'] = fill_nulls(df['A'].values)

# Output for new df['A'].values
[1550.0,
 1545.0,
 1545.0,
 1545.0,
 1545.0,
 1545.0,
 1545.0,
 1540.0,
 1550.0,
 1550.0,
 1550.0,
 1550.0,
 1590.0,
 1549.2857142857142,
 1540.0]
```

Comment: In that case add in your function - `if np.isnan(ls[-1]):
        ls[-1] = non_null_values[-1]`