# How to incrementally take average in Oracle SQL Or Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, numpy

I am bit stuck with this not getting how do i proceed further

**Assume I have below data in table**

**Note** : All the below **column fields** [`NAME , AGE , COURSE , MARKS`] are set to `VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)`

```
NAME | AGE | COURSE | MARKS 
A1   | ABC | MCA    | 5 
B1   | XYZ | MBA    | 10
C1   | PQR | MMS    | 14
D1   | YST | CAT    | 18
```

Using below query I am able to get incremental sum , but not able to apply logic how to get incremental average

**My Query :**

```
select c1.* , SUM(MARKS) Over (Order by c1.NAME) AS CUM_COUNT from EMP c1 order by c1.NAME ASC;
```

**Expected output :**

```
NAME | AGE | COURSE | MARKS | CUM_COUNT | AVGS_CNT      |
A1   | ABC | MCA    | 5     | 5   | 5/1  = 5      |
B1   | XYZ | MBA    | 10    | 15  | 15/2 = 7.5    |
C1   | PQR | MMS    | 14    | 29  | 29/3 = 9.6    |
D1   | YST | CAT    | 18    | 47  | 47/4 = 11.75  |
```

**Solution in oracle OR python appreciated**

**Note :** I have date in Oracle

*The reason behind asking this question as it was asked to me in interview*

Comment: You used analytic `sum` (over "order by ...") - use `avg` instead and you will get exactly what you need, with a single analytic function. You don't need anything else.

Comment: In your query, you succeeded in confusing yourself. You took the cumulative **sum** but you called it `cum_count`. You could also take a cumulative count with the `count()` function (analytic version, also ordered by "name"), and then divide the cumulative sum (which you called `cum_count`) by the actual cumulative count to get the running average. Using `avg` directly is much simpler though.

Comment: @mathguy : Thanks bro

Comment: @mathguy : can you share your solution will upvote it

Comment: As [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142149/calculate-an-incremental-mean-using-python-pandas) says, for a Python/Pandas solution you could do `df['cum_avg'] = df['MARKS'].expanding().mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement @mathguy's answer, here the full query you need:

```
select
  e.*,
  sum(marks) over(order by name) as cum_count,
  1.0 * sum(marks) over(order by name) / count(*) over(order by name) as avgs_cnt
from emp e
```

Result:

```
 NAME  AGE  COURSE  MARKS  CUM_COUNT  AVGS_CNT         
 ----- ---- ------- ------ ---------- ---------------- 
 A1    ABC  MCA     5      5          5                
 B1    XYZ  MBA     10     15         7.5              
 C1    PQR  MMS     14     29         9.66666666666667 
 D1    YST  CAT     18     47         11.75
```

It uses windows functions by qualifying `SUM()` and `COUNT(*)` with `OVER(ORDER BY NAME)`.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc95b8f1c758665f78b870062da7337c).

Comment: May i know why the `1.0`  is given

Comment: Why do it the long way, and not use analytic `avg`? This makes no sense, after the answer I posted twice (both in comments and as a separate answer). Anyway, the OP seems to like this best too - so you are not alone.

Comment: @mathguy You are right. Using `AVG()` is the way to go.

Comment: @codeholic24 `1.0` is needed to ensure the expression willl use floating point division. If it weren't there you would see no decimal places in the result.

Comment: The comment about 1.0 is wrong in Oracle SQL. Oracle doesn't do integer arithmetic ever - not even when it should. Did you test that before posting the solution, or at least the answer to the OP's comment question?

Answer (score 4):

You used analytic `sum` (over "order by ...") - use `avg` instead and you will get exactly what you need, with a single analytic function. You don't need anything else.

In your query, you succeeded in confusing yourself. You took the cumulative sum but you called it `cum_count`. You could also take a cumulative count with the `count()` function (analytic version, also ordered by "name"), and then divide the cumulative sum (which you called `cum_count`) by the actual cumulative count to get the running average. Using analytic `avg` directly is much simpler though.

Caution: (more advanced topic) In your table you have name and age etc. - nothing that is obviously unique (something that could be used as primary key). In analytic functions, if you don't specify the windowing clause and there are possible ties in the order (which is possible with name and age), rows that are "tied" are considered all at once. To break such ties, you could for example use an ordering clause like `order by name, rownum`. That way, when the name is the same, `rownum` will break ties and allow rows to be added to the computation one at a time.

Comment: can you share the solution with an example with ties what you had explained