# Calculating cumulative mean with lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a part of code:

```
res_df = pd.Series([2,10,3,1]).to_frame()
res_df.rename(columns={0:'val'}, inplace=True)
res_df = res_df.reset_index()
res_df['cum_mean'] = res_df.apply(lambda x: res_df[ res_df['index'] <= x['index']  ].agg({'val':'mean'}), axis=1 )
```

and it works properly, I get the correct result.
But I have 2 questions:

1. What is `axis=1` doing there? Iteration is going by rows, why 1, not 0?
2. Is it possible to avoid creaitig `index` column and use DataFrame indexes directly?

I have created this code based a sample but I don't have enough experience to answer these two questions.

Comment: Why not just do it the simple (intended) way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142149/calculate-an-incremental-mean-using-python-pandas

Comment: Great! It is the best and the shortest solution for this case, thanks a lot! And I would be appreciate for the answers - I am learning Python now and it is really important for me to investigate this case - it would be helpful to understand coding deeper